# How to validate Dates in Rails 3? And why does validate see Date instead of String

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to write a date validator.  The problem I'm having is that my validator sees the date_of_birth as a Date object, but it's getting set as a String.  (1) why is it seeing it as a Date instead of a String before validation applies and (2) what should I do to get it to read it as a String instead of a Date.  The problem I'm having is that I want to accept `%m/%d/%Y` dates, but when I enter in 07/05/2010, I get it converted to a Date, where it sees 05 as as the month and 07 as the date.  I'm using Devise, so I'm not sure if it's doing something to the dates in the controller, which I doubt.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  # Setup accessible (or protected) attributes for your model
  attr_accessible :email, :first_name, :last_name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :address, :date_of_birth, as: [:default, :admin]
  attr_accessible :active, :role, as: [ :admin ]

  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name, :address
  validate :valid_date_of_birth

  def date_of_birth=(date_of_birth)
    Rails.logger.info("set date_of_birth: #{date_of_birth}")
    Rails.logger.info("set date_of_birth class: #{date_of_birth.class}")
    self[:date_of_birth] = date_of_birth
  end

  private
  def valid_date_of_birth
    Rails.logger.info "the date of birth: #{date_of_birth}"
    Rails.logger.info "the date of birth class: #{date_of_birth.class}"
    errors.add(:date_of_birth, 'must be a valid datetime') if ((DateTime.strptime(date_of_birth, "%m/%d/%Y") rescue ArgumentError) == ArgumentError)
  end
end
```

So, setting the date_of_birth, I get String.  `valid_date_of_birth` sees it as Date, which is the DB type of date_of_birth.  Am I doing something wrong here that is making this overly complicated?  Is my only option to maintain an additional String field?  How does this work w/ edits?

Comment: BTW, maintaining the additional string field works great.  Just wondering if I'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

If your **date_of_birth** attribute is getting set from the parameters/from the form - then it's coming in as a **String**. The issue comes in where as soon as it gets set to an object - it's being converted to the data type of the one in the database.

So in your **users_controller** in the **create** action:
**params[:user][:date_of_birth]** is coming in as a String

But as soon as you set it to your User object:
**@user.date_of_birth = params[:user][:date_of_birth]** ## it gets converted to the type in the database (Date type).

Solutions:
1) Validate date_of_birth in the controller before assigning.
2) Define an attr_accessor for date_of_birth_input and validate in the model, like you're currently doing it, before assigning to the User object.